# openDrawer() is undefined react native

Tags: react-native

**App.Js**

I have a menu button in header to open the drawer. When I press the header right button it gives me error saying undefined is not an about. [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APoDg.png). But when I for example log a message it works.

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
         <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{
           headerRight: () => {
              return (
                 <Button transparent onPress={() => {
                     this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
                 }}>
                     <Icon name="menu" style={{ fontSize: 30, marginTop: 4 }} />
                  </Button>
                 )
              }}} />
   </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

**DRAWER**

When i try open the drawer from this screen. It works

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Setting" component={SettingScreen}/>
   </Drawer.Navigator>
</View>
```

Comment: where are using openDrawer() in your code and more over what do you want to do when you click headerRight.

Comment: Oh my bad. I want to open the drawer when I press the header right button.

Comment: Is your issue cleared?

Comment: Na it didn't work like that but I found another. Thanks!